# Hiding and Showing list item in listview doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, listview

I have used `ListView` in which each item has two `TextView` and an `ImageView`. I just want to show the second `TextView` only if the user clicks on a list item.

My code,

```
abc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder= (MyAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        if (holder.txtSecond.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            holder.txtSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.image.setRotation(0);
        } else {
            holder.txtSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.image.setRotation(180);
        }
    }
});
```

And the `getView` function looks like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_listview_items, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtFirst =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap map = list.get(position);
    holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get("question").toString());
    holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get("answer").toString());
    return convertView;
}
```

Initially the second `TextView` visibility is `View.GONE`.

The problem is, when I click the item in `ListView`, the second `TextView` is visible. But at the same time some of the other second `TextView`s are also visible. **It worked when the list has minimum number of items**. I tried with 5 items.

Can anyone help me. Thanks!

Comment: please use the position while clicking on item to hide and show the second textview, can u please post your adapter class well?

Comment: in which case the code is executing..? if or else

Comment: I have edited my question.Please refer it now. For the first time, obviously else will be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is wrong, you should save position clicked and call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.
After, in getView add code which will hide/display some views if current position equals to saved click position, something like this:

```
if (position == clickedPosition) {
              holder.txtSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              holder.image.setRotation(0);
} else {
              holder.txtSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              holder.image.setRotation(180);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working.And one more condition needed is **holder.txtSecond.getVisibility()==View.GONE** in if().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to start. Your adapter has so many problems in it. Lets recode your `Activity` and `Adapter` a bit.

So from my understanding you're trying to show a bunch of questions in a `ListView` and then when clicked on a question in your `ListView` you want to expose the answer of that question. Hence, you're keeping the question and the answer in a same map as I'm seeing you're setting the text of your `TextView` from a map like the following. This is not a very good design to serve your purpose.

```
holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get("question").toString());
holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get("answer").toString());
```

Now, I would like to suggest to keep an array of objects that you want to show as your list item. Let us take make a `ListItem` object first.

```
public class ListItem {
    public String question; 
    public String answer;
    public boolean showAnswer = false; // Set the default value to false as at the beginning the answers will be hidden. 
}
```

So as you've observed the `ListItem` class, I'm keeping an object to populate your each list item in your `ListView`. Moreover, I'm keeping a boolean flag `showAnswer` to keep the track of visibility of your answers to be shown or not.

Now pass an array of `ListItem` object to your adapter and implement your `onClickListener` like this. You just have to set the `showAnswer` flag of the selected item to true.

```
abc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(listItemArray[position].showAnswer == false) {
            listItemArray[position].showAnswer = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

Now the implementation of your `getView` function is fairly simple.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    // .. Other code 

    // HashMap map = list.get(position);
    // holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get("question").toString());
    // holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get("answer").toString());

    ListItem listItem = list[position];
    holder.txtFirst.setText(listItem.question);
    holder.txtSecond.setText(listItem.answer);

    if (listItem.showAnswer == true) holder.txtSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else holder.txtSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as..

```
abc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     View sec_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.your_second_tv_id);
     View image_view = view.findViewById(R.id.your_img_view);

           if (sec_tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
              sec_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              image_view.setRotation(0);
              } 
          else {
              sec_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              image_view.setRotation(180);
              }
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the ViewHolder. New views are not created for each new item of the list but old views are recycled. You might have specified in your list item layout file to make second textview gone, but on click you are making it visible. So if this view in which you have made your second textview visible is recycled, your second textview will be visible by default.

To solve this you can add following line to your getView function :

> holder.txtSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);

but do know what it will do, as it might create some other unintended behaviour.